# Get related columns in group by SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with data that relate to countries, simplified it looks something like this:

```
ID | country_id | country_ISO | var_value
1  | 1          | FR          | 10
2  | 2          | BE          | 15
3  | 3          | NL          | 20
4  | 1          | FR          | 6
5  | 2          | BE          | 8
6  | 2          | BE          | 12
```

I would like to get the sum of the values of "var_value", but with that I want to have the country_id as well country_ISO.

I can do this:

```
SELECT
  country_ISO,
  SUM(var_value) AS sum_of_value
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  country_ISO;
```

This query will give me the sum of var_value and the country ISO, but I also want to get the country_id. How do I subquery/self join to get extra columns that are related (in a unique way) to for example country_ISO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `country_iso` depends on `country_id` anyway, just extend the `GROUP BY` by `country_id`.

```
SELECT country_id,
       country_iso,
       sum(var_value) sum_of_value
       FROM table_name
       GROUP BY country_id,
                country_iso;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just include that column also in `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT country_id, country_ISO, SUM(var_value) AS sum_of_value
FROM table_name tn
GROUP BY country_id, country_ISO;
```

Answer (score 1):

If contry_id, contry_ISO matched 1:1, then just group by with contry_id, contry_ISO.

```
SELECT
  contry_id,
  country_ISO,
  SUM(var_value) AS sum_of_value
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  contry_id,
  country_ISO;
```